# Is there any workaround for uploading picture into Google Form responses without having to be signed in to a Google account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, app-inventor

I was wondering if there are any workaround for responding to a form with a picture but without the respondent having to sign in into their google account? Maybe like a a script or something to trick the form to think that every time a respond is sent, it came from the owner.

I'm thinking of having the form to be filled in from an app built on AI2 instead of directly from the actual form as well.

If anyone have any ideas whether this is achievable or not, do respond.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. If you want that kind of functionality, you'll have to create a custom form from the ground up using HTML/CSS/Javascript. You can do that with a GAS WebApp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on this too, but in my opinion it's a two-parter.

First, you upload the file to a separate folder; then, you link the file URL back to the form as a short answer. Separating the two allows you to ignore the pesky "you must have a Google Account to do this" because if you set up your WebApp properly it does look like it's coming from the owner.

This will help you upload the file: https://sites.google.com/view/metricrat-ai2/guides/upload-any-file-to-google-drive-with-ai2

I would suggest downloading the example and adding it to your projects and copying over via your backpack, though. For some reason recreating the code from the pictures he's got up doesn't work for me.

The second half is where it gets tricky. I'm wondering if it's possible to manipulate the final steps in the GAS to return the content URL, but haven't totally wrapped my brain around it yet.